# desiging a FIX message encoder and decoder

Tags: java, quickfix, trading, fix-protocol

I am trying to design a simple FIX message encoder and decoder to encode (convert to FIX) and decode (convert from FIX) my business domain Order objects. I have designed something, but I am not able to achieve the beautiful design I want. Wanted to see if others who have experience building this kind of things have any better design ideas.

This is what I roughly have: a business Object Order, QuickFIX object Message.
I need to generate NewOrder/Cancel/Replace messages and the message could be different for different exchanges.
I can have ReplaceEncoder --> NewOrderEncoder --> AbstractEncoder, CancelEncoder --> AbstractEncoder.
But if I want another dimension to this, like having custom message generation for different exchanges, then it results in too many combinations of hierarchies.

Is my only bet is to mundanely write different code for different exchanges? How others achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Give a try to [FixB](https://github.com/YTEQ/fixb) framework - it is designed mainly for customised or non-standard FIX messages.

Answer (score 2):

*Is my only bet is to mundanely write different code for different exchanges?*

Certainly not. In a FIX message there are compulsory and non compulsory fields. You cannot negotiate on the required fields because then you could not guarantee the authenticity and completeness of the messages. Now I am not saying this is impossible, many counter parties have their own specific user level agreements with exchanges for their own specific messages.

With Quickfix, the XML data dictionary from where the engines confirms the completeness of the messages, is in your hand. Tweak it for your own requirements. You would certainly have multiple sessions. I am not sure if this is possible, haven't tried it myself, does different sessions allow different data dictionaries ? If yes, then use them for different counter parties. If that isn't possible, one way which crosses my mind is add extra code for processing your specific fields, not the whole message, in messages expected from certain counter parties.

One place where I had worked, we were using something on these lines. Receive whatever version you may, but once the message is received convert it into a specific version of FIX message, which only exists inside your system. So your engine basically reads only 1 FIX version of messages. But the added complexity is you have to code a converter. I am not sure how feasible is that for you.

Comment: Sorry did not quite understand that. Say I am sending my messages to CME and ICE. All I need to generate are NewOrder/Cancel/Replace. Now for simplicity assume we only use FIX 4.4. version. There is certainly some code we want to reuse between CME and ICE. But given the above scenario, I don't see any other way but create whole hierarchy of FIX message generation classes for CME and ICE separately and in that case code reuse is not that possible with out duplication. It gets worse because most of the code is generally re-usable except a few tags.

Comment: @user1364959 - Added some details.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will probably come across a similar problem that we have.  That is that each FIX implementation is different.  Some use 4.2 others 4.4, some use some tags others ignore them, some use many of their own tags others use very few.  What we have done is created general FIX sessions with subclasses for FIX 4.2 and 4.4 and then subclasses for each specific sessions (ie individual brokers).  That gives us a reasonable amount of reuse of code for sending and receiving FIX messages.  With just the specifics changed for things like handling account names and passwords etc.

For message generation we have a factory method that returns and adapter.  All the adapters have the same API which will convert our Business order object in to a FIX Message object.  Of course each adapter is specific to the API of the broker.  I guess we could probably reuse some code between the adapters but currently we don't.

Comment: How many Adapters did you have to write eventually? Assume 3 brokers. Assume 2 different protocol versions. Did you really write all 6? reuse will be a bit of a problem in my view.

Comment: I wrote 1 per broker.  Each broker only uses one protocol so there is no need to write any more than one adapter for each.

Comment: Consider 2 brokers using FIX 4.4. Now as I understand, most of the tags in NewOrder/Cancel/Replace will be same. except a few different tags for broker 1 and 2. So, it would be good to reuse the code. Did you use a decorator pattern, which is what I am focusing on for now.

Comment: most but not all tags will be the same.  If you only have two brokers or even three it might be easier just to write individual adapters for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

FIX is an extraordinarily slippery protocol when it comes to message definitions.

In practice, every institution that offers a FIX interface has made modifications to the default message set.  That means, for instance, a FIX4.4 NewOrderSingle message from counterparty A may have different fields than one from counterparty B.

In fact, counterparty A may have made up some fields whole-cloth and added them in.  For any new counterparty, there's a chance you'll encounter fields that you've never seen before.

I've written a few adapters for a few different exchanges, and unfortunately, you're really forced to handle them individually.  You may be able to capitalize on some commonalities, but you can't make any assumptions on that until you've reviewed their FIX interface's specs.

So, short answer to your question:

> Is my only bet is to mundanely write different code for different exchanges?

Yep, pretty much.

Comment: Thanks. Assuming I will write code for different exchanges, "using commonalities" is where the problem raises I guess. Some tags are common between only some exchanges, and some or not. So, there is no clean compile time Inheritance I can use to design this code. Correct?

Comment: Correct.  Given any two exchanges, you might be able to devise a common superclass, but there's no guarantee that a later-added third exchange that will play nice.  I think, practically, each exchange component will need its own converter to translate between your business domain and the FIX required.  Ultimately, I think composition might be more useful for your purpose than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing was writing a base fix layer that applies only the required fix tags.  In the fix spec certain tags are flagged as required for each message type.

Once this message had been created we apply a filter to the message that is specific to a broker and instrument type.

ie if you trade options and equities with Goldman and JPMorgan you'd write the following filters:

Goldman-equity

Goldman-option

JPMorgan-Equity

JPMorgan-option

Each would apply vendor and instrument specific fields to the base message.